# Autofill Address Form for React Native App

Tags: react-native, google-places-api, autofill, google-places-autocomplete

I have an address form on a React Native app.

Something Like

```
streetAddress:
buildingName:
region:
country:
postcode:
```

My idea is to have it autofilled after searching for the address using Google Places API.

I am aware that Google does provide this function - Google Places Autocomplete Address Form. However I can't find anything online about it being used in React Native.

I want to ask is there a way to replicate the autofill functionality? If so, can it all be done in the FE or would it require assistance from the BE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform#maps_places_autocomplete_addressform-javascript

Comment: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete